# Returning length of an array's element

Tags: java, arrays, swing, colors

Hi I was wondering if it was possible for get the length of the elements of an array? I checked out the java docs and the only length I saw that was retrievable was the length of the array itself. My assignment is to use the lengths of the elements to randomize the colors of my bricks. If someone can point in the right direction of getting the lengths of getting the elements length that would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class legos2v2 extends JFrame {
private int startX;
private int startY;
private int legoWidth;
private int legoHeight;
private int baseLength;
private int arcWidth;
private int arcHeight;
private Color[] colors;

// Constructor
public legos2v2() {
    super("Jimmy's LEGOs");
    startX = 20;
    startY = 300;
    legoWidth = 50;
    legoHeight = 20;
    baseLength = 10;
    arcWidth = 2;
    arcHeight = 2;


    // Declare and Array of Colors
    Color[] colors = {Color.red, Color.blue, Color.yellow, Color.green,
            Color.pink, Color.black, Color.magenta, Color.orange,
            Color.cyan};


    // Get length of color
    System.out.println("Array Length = " + colors.length + "\n");

}
// The drawings in the graphics context
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


    // Call the paint method of the JFrame
    super.paint(g);

    int currentX = startX;
    int currentY = startY;

    Random random = new Random();


    // row = 0 is the bottom row
    for (int row = 1; row <= baseLength; row++) {
        currentX = startX;

        for (int col = 0; col <= baseLength - row; col++) {

            g.fillRoundRect(currentX, currentY, legoWidth, legoHeight, arcWidth, arcHeight);


            // Generate random integer from 0 to 8
            int randomIndex = random.nextInt(colors.length);


            g.setColor(this.colors[randomIndex]);
            //Error here   this.colors = colors[randomIndex];



            // Print random integers to screen
            System.out.println(randomIndex);

            currentX = currentX + legoWidth;
        }
        currentY -= legoHeight;
        startX += legoWidth / 2;
    }
}
// The main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    legos2v2 app = new legos2v2();
    // Set the size and the visibility
    app.setSize(550, 325);
    app.setVisible(true);
    // Exit on close is clicked
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: I only see one array in the above code, and it's an array of colors. What is the length of a color? I can't understand your question.

Comment: I think you want rand.nextInt(9), not 8. Calling that with 8 will give you the range 0-7.

Comment: Also, why do you initialize this array of colors if you don't do anything with it? You probably ant to make this aray an instance variable, and replace your long chain of if blocks by `g.setColor(this.colors[randNumber]);`

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: Don’t create a `Random` instance inside a loop. The intended usage is to create a `Random` instance *once* and invoke `nextInt` multiple times.

Comment: @Frank So my professor wasn't really clear with the assignment. This is what the assignment asked for, "For picking the next color for the block, use a java.util.Random object and generate a random integer using the nextInt method. Use the length of the colors array as an argument". So I created the array of colors and I used the nextInt method to produce a random number for each block, and I think its asking me to use the lengths of the colors (ie. blue = length would be 4) to determine which color to assign for each block. Does this make sense or is it asking for something entirely different

Comment: It wants the length of the array, not the individual elements. The array has length = 9. JB has the right idea with his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the teacher asks you to do is what I said in the comments:

1. Initialize an array of colors:

   ```
   Color[] colors = ...;
   ```
2. Generate a random int between 0 (included) and the length of the array (excluded:

   ```
   int randomIndex = random.nextInt(colors.length);
   ```

   This returns an integer which is a valid index for the array of colors.
3. pick the color at the random index:

   ```
    Color color = colors[randomIndex];
   ```

This avoids the need for the ugly chain of `if` blocks to generate a random color.

EDIT:

1. replace `Color[] colors =` by `this.colors =` to initialize the instance variable instead of redefining a local variable with the same name
2. As you were told to do in the other comments, move `Random random = new Random();` before the first for loop
3. As you were told to do in the other comments, override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`.

Comment: I am still having trouble even with your answer. I initalized the arrays of colors in the constructor, but I'm not sure where the second part goes. Shouldn't it go within the "for loop"? If I put it in there, "colors.length" does not work. Sorry, I'm struggling with this right now.

Comment: The array should be initialized just ince, in the constructor. Then, in the for loop, when you need a random color, you can use this array and a randomly-generated index to pick a random color.

Comment: I believe that I updated my code just like you instructed, but still have no luck getting it to work. I keep getting the error for "colors.length" for                                                          `int randomIndex = random.nextInt(colors.length)` I edited my code above. Could you please take a look at it? This is giving me a headache...

Comment: colors must be declared as an instance variable, just like startX, startY, etc. If you declare it as a local variable of the constructor, then it's... local to the constructor, and you can't see it from any other method. Making it an instance variable makes it available in all the methods of the class.

Comment: so I declared it as "private int colors;" and I'm not receiving the error that "int colors" does not have a field length. I can't change my array to from "Color" to "int" because the color arrays will show up as an error message.

Comment: It's an array of colors. Why do you declared it as an int? The declaration must be the same, except it must be declared as an instance variable instead of being declared as a local variable. Why do you try to use Swing, which is a complex framework, before even understanding what a local variable, an instance variable or an array is?

Comment: my professor doesn't go over java topics well which is especially difficult for an intro level class... So I noticed when I have `int randomIndex = random.nextInt(colors.length)` I get a java.lang.NullPointerException. When i replace "colors.length" with 8 it works fine. My professor said I could not hard code the length though... Any suggestions?

Comment: It means you haven't initialized the aray. Edit your question and show your code. But you'll go nowhere f you don't master those basic stuff. Read an introductory Java book.

Comment: -I updated the code. I've been trying to catch on my own time, but I still can't keep up with the course. I think its hard to learn java or any coding by just having the professor read slides, it suppose to be hands on. I took VB before and it was very hands on. I guess it varies by professor.

Comment: See my edited answer. But I repeat: trying to use swing without knowing what a local or instance variable is won't lead you anywhere. read a good book, practice with simple exercises (i.e. no swing involved), and go see your teacher if you think his exercises are way too hard for the level you're supposed to have.

Comment: so to clarify you want me to replace `Color colors = colors[randomIndex]` to `this.colors = colors[randomIndex]` which is located in the second for loop? i tried that and I still get an error for type mismatch "cannot convert from Color to Color. I edited my question again to show you the update.

Comment: No. I want you to do exactly what I stated in m answer: replace `Color[] colors =` by `this.colors =`.

Comment: I did all that but I still get a type mismatch error. I updated my code in the question

Comment: No, you didn't do it. Look at the line after the comment `// Declare and Array of Colors`. Do you see `this.colors =`. No you don't see it. You see `Color[] colors =`.

Comment: I tried it there initially but I received an error message saying that "array constants can only  be used in initalizers"...

Comment: Oh, yeah, the correct way to initialize an array is to do `this.colors = new Color[] {Color.red, Color.blue, ...}`. Didn't you learn that in the course over arrays. Can't you fid the right syntax in your text book? Can't you google for it, or read the Java tutorial on arrays? If every line of code must be given to you by a stranger, what's the point in creating this program. You're supposed to search by yourself, read documentation, be autonomous.

Comment: Sorry for being so dependent. I know its no excuse, but I've fallen behind so much that at times (I should say most times) I'm just stringing code together to get it to work. I blame myself and my professor for my inability to learn java. If I had a professor that actually taught I don't think I would be in this position. Thank you for all your help though. I really appreciate it.